# QCombobox::setView crashes application on windows 7

Tags: c++, windows, qt, windows-7, qt5.5

I want to put **QTreeWidget** inside **QCombobox** object. I've got following code which works well on Linux:

```
QTreeWidget* tree = new QTreeWidget(ui->comboBox);

ui->comboBox->setView(tree);
ui->comboBox->setModel(tree->model());
```

... but when I try to run this code on x64 windows 7 it crashes application  with runtime error:

[image]

---

Things I have tried:

1. Reinstall all MS VC++ redistrutable libraries (versions 2005-2008-2010-2012-2015, 32- and 64-bit versions)
2. Move **ALL** Qt DDL-s to application folder
3. Move **qwindows.dll** to platforms folder
4. Compile application with -O0 flag
5. Trying something else instead of **QTreeWidget** (e.g. **QListWidget** crashes application too).

---

My environment:

**OS**: Windows 7 x86_64

**Qt Version**: 5.5.1 Community Edition, installed by Online installer

**Compiler**: mingw 4.9.2 **32-bit version** (it's important, I didn't try on 64-bit builds).

---

You can download the test project from here: [Github Repo](https://github.com/MooNDeaR/combobox_setview_crash)

Comment: This is the error message you get for an optimized build, upon termination, after the runtime detects an error condition. What happens when you run a debugging build under a debugger?

Comment: @CodyGray, nothing happens. Here's my stack when error window shows (http://imgur.com/LrqxIkn). After that application just exits. No SEGFAULT-s, no other information.

Comment: Well, okay, but if you're getting a call stack, the debugger is breaking on a specific line of code (and the application will not be terminated). Is that the code you've shown in the question? Anyway, I could guess that this is because a different control cannot be hosted inside of a QComboBox control. Does the documentation explicitly say that this is possible? Generally this would not be true with native Windows controls, but Qt loves to reimplement the native controls, so it might be possible there if they've taken special pains to allow it.

Comment: @CodyGray, I've got a call stack because I set a breakpoint on calling setView method. After pressing F10 (next step in debug) application just crashes without any debug information. I don't know where and why it's crashes. I just see error and after pressing OK application closes. There is no place in documentation where it is allowed to user one control inside another, but I don't this. I put only one View inside another. If I remember right, in WINAPI every control is "window" and in Windows it is especially native to put one window inside another.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the QComboBox::setView() documentation:

> make sure to call setModel() on the combobox with the convenience
>   widgets model *before* calling this function.

Emphasis added by me ;)

Comment: Thank you and sorry for wasting your time.